# How to get the html inside a $node rather than just the $nodeValue

Tags: php, dom, glob, nodevalue

### Description of the current situation:

I have a folder full of pages (pages-folder), each page inside that folder has (among other things) a div with `id="short-info"`.
I have a code that pulls all the `<div id="short-info">...</div>` from that folder and displays the text inside it by using `textContent` (which is for this purpose the same as `nodeValue`)

**The code that loads the divs:**

```
<?php
$filename = glob("pages-folder/*.php");
sort($filename);
foreach ($filename as $filenamein) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($filenamein);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $elements = $xpath->query("*//div[@id='short-info']");

        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                echo $node->textContent;
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Now the problem is that if the page I am loading has a child, like an image: `<div id="short-info"> <img src="picture.jpg"> Hello world </div>`, the output will only be *Hello world* rather than the image and then *Hello world*.

### Question:

How do I make the code display the full html inside the div id="short-info" including for instance that image rather than just the text?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to make an undocumented call on the node.

`$node->c14n()` Will give you the HTML contained in `$node`.

Crazy right? I lost some hair over that one.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#88441

**Update**

This will modify the html to conform to strict HTML. It is better to use

`$html = $Node->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $Node );`

Instead.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want what amounts to 'innerHTML', which PHP's dom doesn't directly support. One workaround for it is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#92571) in the PHP docs.

Another option is to take the `$node` you've found, insert it as the top-level element of a new DOM document, and then call `saveHTML()` on that new document.