# How can parse html code with tags in PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have an html page with code:

```
<div id="content">
  <nav>some menu</nav>
  <article>
   <img src="photo.jpg" />
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <div class="articleContent">
      <p>text,text,text</p>
      <h4>sub title</h4>
      <p>text,text,text</p>
      <img src="">
      <p>text,text,text</p>
   </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

and i want get div.articleContent with all html tags:

```
<p>text,text,text</p>
<h4>sub title</h4>
<p>text,text,text</p>
<img src="photo.jpg">
<p>text,text,text</p>
```

my code:

```
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html = file_get_contents('url.html');
$dom = new DomDocument();

@ $dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$content = $xpath->query("//div[@class='articleContent']");
```

but i only get plain text:

> text,text,text sub title text,text,text text,text,text

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6739848/10116997

Comment: Can anyone else help me?

Comment: I have suggested an answer, hope it helps

Comment: have you tried ```$content->item(0)->c14n();```?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you may try to use the following method:

1. Use saveHTML() to put the loaded HTML file into a string ($string1)
2. Use the get_string_between function to get the string between [div class=articleContent] and [/div] (I use square brackets so that you can see them here.)

The codes below should work as expected:

```
<?php

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}



$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('url.html');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$string1= $doc->saveHTML();

echo get_string_between($string1, '<div class="articleContent">','</div>');


?>
```

The following is the url.html file (please put it in the same directory of the php file)

```
<div id="content">
  <nav>some menu</nav>
  <article>
   <img src="photo.jpg" />
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <div class="articleContent">
      <p>text,text,text</p>
      <h4>sub title</h4>
      <p>text,text,text</p>
      <img src="photo.jpg">
      <p>text,text,text</p>
   </div>
  </article>
</div>
```